# Can't get rid of a certain barrier thrown by a site while logging in

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to log into a site using selenium but I come across [this issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyzlZ.jpg). After entering the username when the script is supposed to enter the password, that page appears. When I do the same manually in chrome browser, I get success.

I've tried with:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

link = 'https://merchants.google.com/mc/default?hl=en&fmp=1&utm_id=gfr&mcsubid=us-en-z-g-mc-gfr'

username = "your_gmail_id"
password = "your_password"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get(link)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input#identifierId"))).send_keys(username)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#identifierNext"))).click()
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[aria-label='Enter your password']"))).send_keys(password)
```

> How can I get rid of that barrier?

Comment: The solution I got here and the solutions in the link above couldn't solve the issue. How come this post becomes duplicate?

Comment: Finally, I've been able to solve the issue. I could paste here a working solution but the problem is the post is locked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to activate the 'less secure app access' in your google account security configurations. Also, make sure you don't have 2-Step verification ON.

[image]

Comment: I've activated `less secure app access` option and deactivated `2-Step verification ON` but still having the same page that I've shown in the image while running the script.

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using?  @robots.txt

Comment: This one `Version 83.0.4103.116 (Official Build) (32-bit)`. I'm really astonished to see that this post has been closed.

Comment: Please try the following: 1)  Uninstall and install again google chrome to see if this solve the issue 2) Create a fake google account with no configurations and try to login using this new account 3) see this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HkgDRRWrZKg&feature=youtu.be it have helped other people to solve the problem @robots.txt

Comment: I've followed all the steps possible. However, the link that I tried with in my post is still showing that page.

Comment: I even tried with [this link](https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&service=mail&sacu=1&rip=1&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin) and encountered the same issue.

Comment: At this point the only solution I can think of using selenium is to downgrade the google chrome version, please refer to the following link for more information: https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7125792?hl=en  another option is to open a new case in google help. @robots.txt

Comment: Tried with version 80 just now but no luck. Thanks.